# Excel VBA Find cell address in range based on min to max for where class

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Please assist me for following scenario

I need to go thorough one range and find Minimum value.If corresponding value in another range matches, then I need to find column number.

I am able to do with following code; however when there is more than one  minimum value, following code always give fist minimum value column number. it is not moving to next minimum value column even if condition is not met.

it is kind of where class I am trying to apply

```
        MyOrder = 1
        Do Until wksSkill.Cells(MyRow, MyColNum).Value <> "Exclude"
            MyColNum = Application.Evaluate("=CELL(""col"", INDEX(" & MyColRange.Address(0, 0) & ", MATCH(SMALL(" & MyColRange.Address(0, 0) & ",   " & MyOrder & " ), " & MyColRange.Address(0, 0) & ", 0)))")
            MyOrder = MyOrder + 1
        Loop
```

First "MyColNum" value passed from another if statement, then it will take the function output. It works till the range has one minimum value.

Please assist me for any other alternative

Comment: `MyColNum` should give you column of this minimal value, and then you want to check if in this column and `MyRow` row exists value "Exclude", am I right?

Comment: @Limak Thanks for looking into this. Yes, what you said is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what I can propose, is to find min value in range, and then loop through every column in that range and check if this min value occurs there and if value "Exclude" occurs in `MyRow`. I have some example values in my code:

```
Sub mac()
Dim minVal As Double
Dim MyColRange As Range, rng As Range
Dim wksSkill As Worksheet

MyRow = 6
Set wksSkill = Sheets("Arkusz1")
Set MyColRange = wksSkill.Range("A1:E5")

minVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(MyColRange)

For Each rng In MyColRange.Columns
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(minVal, rng, 0)) Then
        If wksSkill.Cells(MyRow, rng.Column) = "Exclude" Then
            MsgBox "Column " & rng.Column
        End If
    End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the same code; however when I loop through hundreds of rows, this is not giving correct minimum value column. I will add few more clarity on my question. MyColRange would be A1:Z1 and Data in the range would be 1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,0,1,0...etc So there are more than one minimum value at a time is possible; however minimum value column in Cells(MyRow,Minimus Value Column) may not have "Exclude". Then I need to go next minimum Value column, ie Value is remain Zero here..it may differ..I think, above code needs some modification. I tied, will you verify this..

Comment: Try to set `MyColRange` on whole range where data is stored (as in my code), for example: `Set MyColRange = wksSkill.Range("A1:Z10000"). I don't understand how can be more than one minimum value. Maybe some screen (not with whole your data, but, let say, first 10 rows) can make it clear for me.

Comment: It's an algorithm for team, each column represent one person, assume 10 person. Beginning data in all column will be Zero.Once the condition is met in "MyRow" corresponding Person Data, ie MyColRange data keep on changing. So, there is chance of having duplicate data in MyColRange; and problem is, not all the time MyRow condition matches; hence I need to keep on moving with next minimum data in MyColRange (Eg. Value in A1=1,Value in B1=1..Here I check condition in A1 FIrst, if fails I need to move to B1)..I think, Array may help I am not good at VBA. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, your description is a bit too chaotic, still can't catch what you need. I think I am missing something that is obvious for you, because I can't see sheet that we are talking about. So please provide me some screen with explanation, what is `MyColRange`, what is `MyRow`, what is `Person Data` and what should be the outcome of algorithm. You can do it by editing your main post.

Comment: @Limark, I found alternative; however I got struck in Array formula. Assume, my Range has Value like A1:F1 = {1,0,2,1,0,3}. I want to use one array formula dynamically to find value as 1st small as "0", 2nd Small as 1,3rd as 2 and 4th as 3. Formula =Small(A1:F1,k) give second small as 0. Any formula to remove duplicate would be helpful. I tried this one, SMALL(IF(A1:F1>SMALL(A1:F1,B1),A1:F1,""),B1)   , here B1 represent my small value I enter